# How can I change date type for graph labels

Tags: python, date, pandas, matplotlib, label

[image]

You can see `out[7]` -> date type `2015.01.02`
but
You can see o`ut[17]` -> `x-axis` on graph only shows `0, 50, 100`

How can I change `x-axis` like `2015.01.02`

Any suggestions on this please ?

Comment: Can you add sample of dataframe and code as text instead of picture?

Comment: And welcome to Stack Overflow. You can check [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: my eyes hurt when I look at these pics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try first convert column `date` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last change datetime format of `axis` `x` by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) and [`set_major_formatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] )
print df
        date   a   b  c
0 2015-01-02  10  20  3
1 2015-01-05  40  50  6
2 2015-01-06  70  80  8
3 2015-01-07  80  50  9
4 2015-01-08  90  50  3
5 2015-01-09  10  20  3
6 2015-01-10  40  50  6
7 2015-01-11  70  80  8
8 2015-01-12  80  50  9
9 2015-01-13  90  50  3

a = df['a'].pct_change()
b = df['b'].pct_change()
c = df['c'].pct_change()
df['corr'] = pd.rolling_corr(a,b,3)
df = df.set_index('date')
print df
             a   b  c      corr
date                           
2015-01-02  10  20  3       NaN
2015-01-05  40  50  6       NaN
2015-01-06  70  80  8       NaN
2015-01-07  80  50  9  0.941542
2015-01-08  90  50  3  0.914615
2015-01-09  10  20  3  0.776273
2015-01-10  40  50  6  0.999635
2015-01-11  70  80  8  0.985112
2015-01-12  80  50  9  0.941542
2015-01-13  90  50  3  0.914615
```

```
ax = df['corr'].plot()

ticklabels = df.index.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
plt.show()
```

[image: graph_corr]

EDIT by comment:
It seems like bug, but you can change `index` and then rotate `labels`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] )
#print df


a = df['a'].pct_change()
b = df['b'].pct_change()
c = df['c'].pct_change()
df['corr'] = pd.rolling_corr(a,b,3)

df = df.set_index('date')
print df
             a   b  c      corr
date                           
2015-01-02  10  20  3       NaN
2015-01-05  40  50  6       NaN
2015-01-06  70  80  8       NaN
2015-01-07  80  50  9  0.941542
2015-01-08  90  50  3  0.914615
2015-01-09  10  20  3  0.776273
2015-01-10  40  50  6  0.999635
2015-01-11  70  80  8  0.985112
2015-01-12  80  50  9  0.941542
2015-01-13  90  50  3  0.914615
```

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
print df
             a   b  c      corr
2015.01.02  10  20  3       NaN
2015.01.05  40  50  6       NaN
2015.01.06  70  80  8       NaN
2015.01.07  80  50  9  0.941542
2015.01.08  90  50  3  0.914615
2015.01.09  10  20  3  0.776273
2015.01.10  40  50  6  0.999635
2015.01.11  70  80  8  0.985112
2015.01.12  80  50  9  0.941542
2015.01.13  90  50  3  0.914615

ax = df['corr'].plot()

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: I appreciate this ^^

Comment: Becouse it is set by `df.index.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')`

Comment: thx. so how can i change date range which cover whole period......from 2015-01-02 to 2015-01-13